# SQL How to Insert where NOT EXISTS Criteria from two tables

Tags: sql, where-clause, exists

I have two tables T1 & T2

```
T1 has ID, Sl_No and Active (1, 123, 'Y')
T2 has ID, Sl_No, tDate and OutYesOrNo (1, 123, tdate(CURDATE()), 'Y')
```

T1 is master table. I want to insert Sl_No from T1 into T2 where T1.Active = 'Y' and T2.OutYesorNo <> 'Y' and T2.tDate does not Exist.

I tried this but it is not working

```
INSERT INTO T2 (Sl_No)
SELECT Sl_No FROM T1
WHERE (T1. Active = 'Y' OR T1.Active = 'y') 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Sl_No From T2 WHERE tDate = CURDATE()
                AND T2.OutYesorNo='Y' OR T1.OutYesorNo = 'y')
```

Comment: "not working" how? What happens if you execute the whole select, and just its sub-query?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your query seems to have nothing to do with the conditions that you mention.

Comment: Sample data I have given in the Round Brackets.

Comment: Sample data I have given in the Round Brackets. T1 is a master table with set of records. Column T1.Active is not in T2. But Sl_No Column is there in T2. T2 also has additional columns of tDate & OutYesorNo which are not there in T1. The ID columns of both tables are Primary Key for sake of it. I Need to Copy all T1.Sl_No where T1.Active is 'Y' into T2 everyday but In case T2.OutYesorNo ='Y', T1.Sl_No should not be inserted.

Comment: Dear jarlh when I execute, unwanted records are inserted. So I tried DELETE FROM T2 WHERE ID > (
    SELECT min(ID) FROM T2
     WHERE OutYesorNo ='Y' or OutYesorNo ='y' ) but MySQL throws error "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'T2' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Is it just missing parentheses around the `T2.OutYesorNo='Y' OR T1.OutYesorNo = 'y'`?